# Is there lexographical version of searchsorted in numpy?

Tags: python, search, numpy

I have two arrays which are lex-sorted.

```
In [2]: a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,5,6,6])
In [3]: b = np.array([10,20,30,5,10,100,10,30,40])
In [4]: ind = np.lexsort((b, a)) # sorts elements first by a and then by b
In [5]: print a[ind]
[1 1 1 2 2 3 5 6 6]
In [7]: print b[ind]
[ 10  20  30   5  10 100  10  30  40]
```

I want to do a binary search for (2, 7) and (5, 150) expecting (4, 7) as the answer.

```
In [6]: np.lexsearchsorted((a,b), ([2, 5], [7,150]))
```

We have searchsorted function but that works only on 1D arrays.

Comment: can you give more information about what you are trying to do? this implementation in numpy seems strange to me.

Comment: I have two set of timeseries both keyed by same key. something like (user, time, location) and (user, time, purchase) in two separate places. I am trying to join both of them to get something like (user, time, location, purchase)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Edited to reflect comment.

```
def comp_leq(t1,t2):
    if (t1[0] > t2[0]) or ((t1[0] == t2[0]) and (t1[1] > t2[1])):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def bin_search(L,item):
    from math import floor
    x = L[:]
    while len(x) > 1:
        index = int(floor(len(x)/2) - 1)
        #Check item
        if comp_leq(x[index], item):
            x = x[index+1:]
        else:
            x = x[:index+1]
    out = L.index(x[0])
    #If greater than all
    if item >= L[-1]:
        return len(L)
    else:
        return out

def lexsearch(a,b,items):
    z = zip(a,b)
    return [bin_search(z,item) for item in items]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1,1,1,2,2,3,5,6,6]
    b = [10,20,30,5,10,100,10,30,40]
    print lexsearch(a,b,([2,7],[5,150])) #prints [4,7]
```

Comment: By lex-sort, I meant sorting based on two columns the one does by lexsort() method of numpy.

Comment: @pvncad Edited now that I understand. Also, I think the first case should return 4?

Comment: your answer is correct. i am doing something similar now and looking for a numpy style solution so that it works faster on larger arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to do it for a set of (exactly) 2 lexsorted arrays

You might be able to make it faster if you create a set of `values[-1]`, and than create a dictionary with the boundries for them.

I haven't checked other cases apart from the posted one, so please verify it's not bugged.

```
def lexsearchsorted_2(arrays, values, side='left'):
    assert len(arrays) == 2
    assert (np.lexsort(arrays) == range(len(arrays[0]))).all()
    # here it will be faster to work on all equal values in 'values[-1]' in one time
    boundries_l = np.searchsorted(arrays[-1], values[-1], side='left')
    boundries_r = np.searchsorted(arrays[-1], values[-1], side='right')
    # a recursive definition here will make it work for more than 2 lexsorted arrays
    return tuple([boundries_l[i] + 
                  np.searchsorted(arrays[-2[boundries_l[i]:boundries_r[i]], 
                                  values[-2][i], 
                                  side=side) 
                  for i in range(len(boundries_l))])
```

Usage:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,5,6,6])
b = np.array([10,20,30,5,10,100,10,30,40])
lexsearchsorted_2((b, a), ([7,150], [2, 5]))  # return (4, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. One problem with is it will create two new arrays.

Comment: yes, but their size is the size of `values`, so it is still works well for large `a` and `b`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and came up with a different solution. You can treat the multi-column data instead as single entries using a structured data type. A structured data type will allow one to use argsort/sort on the data (instead of lexsort, although lexsort appears faster at this stage) and then use the standard searchsorted. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import repeat

# Setup our input data
# Every row is an entry, every column what we want to sort by
# Unlike lexsort, this takes columns in decreasing priority, not increasing
a = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,3,5,6,6])
b = np.array([10,20,30,5,10,100,10,30,40])
data = np.transpose([a,b])

# Sort the data
data = data[np.lexsort(data.T[::-1])]

# Convert to a structured data-type
dt = np.dtype(zip(repeat(''), repeat(data.dtype, data.shape[1]))) # the structured dtype
data = np.ascontiguousarray(data).view(dt).squeeze(-1) # the dtype change leaves a trailing 1 dimension, ascontinguousarray is required for the dtype change

# You can also first convert to the structured data-type with the two lines above then use data.sort()/data.argsort()/np.sort(data)

# Search the data
values = np.array([(2,7),(5,150)], dtype=dt) # note: when using structured data types the rows must be a tuple
pos = np.searchsorted(data, values)

# pos is (4,7) in this example, exactly what you would want
```

This works for any number of columns, uses the built-in numpy functions, the columns remain in the "logical" order (decreasing priority), and it should be quite fast.

A compared the two two numpy-based methods time-wise.

#1 is the recursive method from @j0ker5 (the one below extends his example with his suggestion of recursion and works with any number of lexsorted rows)

#2 is the structured array from me

They both take the same inputs, basically like `searchsorted` except `a` and `v` are as per `lexsort`.

```
import numpy as np

def lexsearch1(a, v, side='left', sorter=None):
    def _recurse(a, v):
        if a.shape[1] == 0: return 0
        if a.shape[0] == 1: return a.squeeze(0).searchsorted(v.squeeze(0), side)
        bl = np.searchsorted(a[-1,:], v[-1], side='left')
        br = np.searchsorted(a[-1,:], v[-1], side='right')
        return bl + _recurse(a[:-1,bl:br], v[:-1])
    a,v = np.asarray(a), np.asarray(v)
    if v.ndim == 1: v = v[:,np.newaxis]
    assert a.ndim == 2 and v.ndim == 2 and a.shape[0] == v.shape[0] and a.shape[0] > 1
    if sorter is not None: a = a[:,sorter]
    bl = np.searchsorted(a[-1,:], v[-1,:], side='left')
    br = np.searchsorted(a[-1,:], v[-1,:], side='right')
    for i in xrange(len(bl)): bl[i] += _recurse(a[:-1,bl[i]:br[i]], v[:-1,i])
    return bl

def lexsearch2(a, v, side='left', sorter=None):
    from itertools import repeat
    a,v = np.asarray(a), np.asarray(v)
    if v.ndim == 1: v = v[:,np.newaxis]
    assert a.ndim == 2 and v.ndim == 2 and a.shape[0] == v.shape[0] and a.shape[0] > 1
    a_dt = np.dtype(zip(repeat(''), repeat(a.dtype, a.shape[0])))
    v_dt = np.dtype(zip(a_dt.names, repeat(v.dtype, a.shape[0])))
    a = np.asfortranarray(a[::-1,:]).view(a_dt).squeeze(0)
    v = np.asfortranarray(v[::-1,:]).view(v_dt).squeeze(0)
    return a.searchsorted(v, side, sorter).ravel()


a = np.random.randint(100, size=(2,10000)) # Values to sort, rows in increasing priority
v = np.random.randint(100, size=(2,10000)) # Values to search for, rows in increasing priority

sorted_idx = np.lexsort(a)
a_sorted = a[:,sorted_idx]
```

And the timing results (in iPython):

```
# 2 rows
%timeit lexsearch1(a_sorted, v)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.4 ms per loop

%timeit lexsearch2(a_sorted, v)
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

# 10 rows
%timeit lexsearch1(a_sorted, v)
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop

%timeit lexsearch2(a_sorted, v)
100 loops, best of 3: 14.7 ms per loop
```

Overall the structured array approach is faster, and can be made even faster if you design it to work with the flipped and transposed versions of `a` and `v`. It gets even faster as the numbers of rows/keys goes up, barely slowing down when going from 2 rows to 10 rows.

I did not notice any significant timing difference between using `a_sorted` or a and `sorter=sorted_idx` so I left those out for clarity.

I believe that a really fast method could be made using Cython, but this is as fast as it is going to get with pure pure Python and numpy.